# Adding images to a JSon array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

I have a JSon array that displays in a JQuery Mobile list. It shows the description + price, but I'd like to add a picture Icon to the left.

Any pointers on how I could achieve that ?
Can I add an image tag to the "brand" ? Brand is where I'd like the image to display.

Thanks !

Here's my code.

```
// Json array
var productList = {"products": [
    {"brand": "brand1", "description": "Product 1", "price": "03.25 "},
    {"brand": "brand2", "description": "Product 4", "price": "01.10 "},
    {"brand": "brand3", "description": "Product 3", "price": "04.21 "},
    {"brand": "brand4", "description": "Product 2", "price": "15.24 "},
    {"brand": "brand5", "description": "Product 5", "price": "01.52 "},
    {"brand": "brand6", "description": "Product 6", "price": "12.01 "},
    {"brand": "brand7", "description": "Product 7", "price": "05.24 "}
```

]
};

// Name Descending

function loadList() {

```
var list = $("#productList").listview();
```

var prods = productList.products.sort(function(a, b) {return a.description > b.description;});
$.each(prods, function() {
    list.append("

" + this.description + "  :       " + this.price + "

");
});

```
// CALL SORT BY NAME DESCENDING
$(function(){
```

$("#sort-list").click(loadList2);
  });

$(list).listview("refresh");

}

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here; I mean, of course you can add an image if you want to.  What in particular is it that you're having trouble with?

Comment: I'm just unsure how to add an image to my list, that's all really. Instead of the text brand, I'd like to have a picture.

Comment: Well you can just put the URL in there, no?  Just have another property in the objects in the array, like "img", and have its value be the URL.  Then when you're building the list, you'd include an `<img>` tag with that URL as the "src" attribute.

Comment: I tried this already. {"brand": <img src="images/album-bb.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">, "description": "Product 1", "price": "03.25 "},

doesnt work =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing out an HTML list derived from a JSON array. So, one suggestion for achieving what you want:

1. Modify the JSON produced so that instead of the `brand` text you have in there at the moment, you provide the URI for the relevant image
2. Modify the `loadList()` function so that you write out an `img` tag as part of your HTML, using the URI passed-in from your JSON as that image tag's `src` attribute.

Comment: So if I get this right it would be something like 

var productList = {"products": [
    {"brand": "<img src="images/album-bb.jpg" class="ui-li-thumb">", "description": "Product 1", "price": "03.25 "},

and in my function

list.append("<li>"+ this.images/album-bb.jpg + this.description + "  :       " + this.price + "</li>");

Comment: You don't need the whole HTML fragment for the image in your JSON--let your code do that when writing out the list--just the image path. Also, you are writing the image path to the object element `brand`, so reference that when doing your output. The code you've supplied won't work.