# Passing an image through parameters, JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, mobile

I have a simple JQuery Product list. When a user click an item, it opens a "master page" called details in which I pass the parameters like Brand, Description and Price.

I'm trying to pass the image but I have no clue how I can do this. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Heres how I pass the parameters :

```
 var productId = getParameterByName("productId", $(this).data("url"));
    $.mobile.pageLoading();
    var product = catalog.products[productId];

    $('#productDescription').html(product.description);
    $('#productBrand').html(product.brand);
    $('#productPrice').html(product.price);
    $('#productThumbnail').html(product.thumbnail);

    $.mobile.pageLoading(true);
```

Now if I can pass the Brand, description and price because they are text. But I dont know how to pass the image... I tried the following and it shows the URI of the image.

```
<div align="center">
            <label>Thumbnail</label>
            <label id="productThumbnail">Thumb</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: BTW this is my array if it can help...

var catalog = {"products": [
    {"thumbnail": '/pub/3/resources/ti/store/mobile/chrome.png', "brand": "Google", "description": "Chrome", "price": "0.00"},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you

```
$('#productThumbnail').html("<img src='"+product.thumbnail+"' alt='Thumbnail' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked this before: [Adding images to a JSon array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572835/adding-images-to-a-json-array)

You can't set `#productThumbnail`'s `html` attribute, you need to set its `src` instead, using the image URI passed-in from `product.thumbnail` (mkilmanas's answer tells you how).

Comment: I know, I know... I ask a lot of questions but I'm learning. Sometimes I might ask similar questions by mistake. But I just really appreciate the help. The more I learn, the less questions I'll have and someday I'll be answering people instead of asking